# Create and Export file as .xml - Jmeter

Tags: java, xml, file, jmeter

Is there any code (Java, for example) that creates a file in .xml format and saves it in a folder?
I can't find...
I've searched in several places, but to no success. =//

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you really tried to search? There is an official documentation for Java, i.e. check [Writing Out a DOM as an XML File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/writingDom.html) guide

Also be aware that there is no Java support in JMeter (unless you decide to [develop your own plugin)](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-develop-a-jmeter-plugin-intro-and-best-practices) and it's [recommended to use Groovy for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it might be a better idea to look for code to copy and paste in [Groovy documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_creating_xml). A quote from the above page:

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)

xml.records() {
    car(name: 'HSV Maloo', make: 'Holden', year: 2006) {
        country('Australia')
        record(type: 'speed', 'Production Pickup Truck with speed of 271kph')
    }
    car(name: 'Royale', make: 'Bugatti', year: 1931) {
        country('France')
        record(type: 'price', 'Most Valuable Car at $15 million')
    }
}

def records = new XmlSlurper().parseText(writer.toString())
```

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there aren't any out of box features in JMeter to process XML. You can use [Groovy XML objects/operations](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html) to read/write XML